# Sort history on number of occurrences

Tags: unix, sorting, history, uniq

Basically I want to print the 10 
most used commands that are stored in the 
bash history but they still have to be proceeded 
by the number that indicates when it was used;

I got this far:
    history | cut -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 3,5 | sort -k 2 -n

Which should sort the second column of the number of occurrences from the command in that row... But it doesn't do that. I know I can head -10 the pipe at the end to take the highest ten of them, but I'm kinda stuck with the sorting part.

Comment: Try extending with `sort -k2n | uniq -c | sort -k1nr | head -10` (or what ever number you like. This will leave the count generated by the `uniq -c` portion in our output. Remove or change the value in `head -10` to see varying amount of history. (I don't have time to test now) Good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 10 most used commands stored in your history:

```
history | sed -e 's/ *[0-9][0-9]* *//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
```

This gives you the most used command line entries by removing the history number (`sed`), counting (`sort | uniq -c`), sorting by frequency (`sort -rn`) and showing only the top ten entries.

If you just want the commands alone:

```
history | awk '{print $2;}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10
```

Both of these strip the history number. Currently, I have no idea, how to achieve that in one line.

Comment: How do I also account for piped top level commands? E.g., In a program `foo 1 2 3 | bar`, I want `foo` and `bar` to be counted.

Comment: @Abhijit This is a bit more involved. You could split a command line at the pipe symbols. But right now I have no idea how to do this easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the top used commands in your history file, you will have to count the instances in your history. `awk` can be used to do this. In the following code, the `awk` segment will create a hashtable with commands as the key and the number of times they appear as the value. This is printed out with the last history number for that command and sorted:

```
history | cut -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 3,5 | awk '{a[$2]++;b[$2]=$1} END{for (i in a) {print b[i], i, a[i]}}' | sort -k3 -rn | head -n 10
```

Output looks like:

```
975 cd 142
972 vim 122
990 ls 118
686 hg 90
974 mvn 51
939 bash 39
978 tac 32
958 cat 28
765 echo 27
981 exit 17
```

If you don't want the last column you could pipe the output through `cut -d' ' -f1,2`.